# Visual Studio doesn't put space in between 'internalclass' due to EditorConfig

Tags: c#, editorconfig

When I create a new class using Visual Studio, it produces the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test;
internalclass Test
{
}
```

The issue is that there is no space between `internal` and `class`, which I want to fix. It is caused by `csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped` and Visual Studio itself. I disabled ReSharper and it was the same.

Tools:

- Visual Studio 2022 - latest update
- ReSharper 2021.3.3 built on 2022-01-25

### .editorconfig

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.{csproj,json,md,nuspec,yml}]
indent_size = 2

[*.{sln,xml}]
indent_style = tab

[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
```

Comment: What makes you think that producing an invalid template is a property of .editorconfig? Is it actually an R# issue -- if you disable R#, does it still happen? If you get rid of the .editorconfig entirely, does it still happen? If the answer to both of those is "No", then start removing bits of the .editorconfig bit-by-bit until you figure out what causes the problem.

Comment: @canton7 good idea, actually. Thank you for that, updating my question in a moment

Comment: (Read [mcve] for more advice on how to create a *minimal* sample)

Comment: @canton7, just did. Everybody is able to reproduce it by creating a new project and using `csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped`. It's not caused by ReSharper

Comment: Huh, nice find. I can reproduce that. Looks like it's already been reported and fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58974

Comment: @canton7, thanks! you can write that as an answer. It should be live in the next VS update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58974) in Visual Studio. It has [been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/59091), and the fix should be included in the next Visual Studio release.